# AJAX Multiple FileUpload inside Gridview

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview, inside which there is an AjaxFileUpload control in each row for a user to attach multiple files. The problem is I am unable to find the AjaxFileUpload control inside gridview.

GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server">
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="fupReports" runat="server" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" OnUploadComplete="fupReports_UploadComplete" Width="300px" />
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind:

```
Protected Sub fupReports_UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxFileUploadEventArgs)
    Dim filename As String = e.FileName
    Dim dstnPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath
    Dim fupReports As AjaxFileUpload = TryCast(gridview1.FindControl("fupReports"), AjaxFileUpload)

    fupReports.SaveAs(dstnPath + filename)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
Protected Sub fupReports_UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxFileUploadEventArgs)

    Dim filename As String = e.FileId
    TryCast(sender, AjaxFileUpload).SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads/") + filename)

End Sub
```